# Mootools equivalent of $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I'm looking for a Mootools equivalent of Jquery:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
```

I tried with:

```
$$(data).each( function(i, item) {
Array.each(data, function(i, item) {
Object.each(data, function(i, item) {
```

But it's not :S

Thanks for help

Comment: it's what happens when you use too much jQuery. swapping the arguments to `$.each` callback functions is the singlemost stupid decision jQuery devs ever made, in the face of MooTools, prototype, DOJO etc and last but not least, ES5's own `forEach`, `every`, `some` etc array methods that are actual browser standard and accept args in the order of `item`, `index`, `scope`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.each()` should work according to the [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array%3aArray-each):

```
Array.each(['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'], function(day, index){
    alert('name:' + day + ', index: ' + index);
}); // alerts 'name: Sun, index: 0', 'name: Mon, index: 1', etc.
```

It seems you just got the order of parameters in the callback wrong. It is

```
fn(item, index, object)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can just use standard javascript:

```
data.forEach(function(item, i) {
    // Your code here
}, this);
```